# Is there a common template or mnemonic for a take-off briefing?

Tags: takeoff, preflight

I know that a take-off briefing is a good idea so that your actions are a bit "spring-loaded" should a unexpected event occur.  Is there a common template on mnemonic out there (something like CRAFT for instrument clearances)?

For example, I was talking to a flight instructor who broke down the altitudes based on the elevation of the airport and what he would do in the event of an engine failure at or below those altitudes (example, airport elevation is 427 ft MSL, then 900 ft MSL, land straight ahead, 1400 MSL, turn back to runway...) The notable thing in this case is that he pre-computed the altitudes so he wouldn't have to think about them if something happened and had a straight-ahead, and turn back to airport plan and altitude.

Comment: Do you mean pre-takeoff vital actions, or captains briefing?

Comment: I don’t have one for emergencies, but I get HAAPY on taking the runway, Heading, Ailerons, Airspeed, Power, Pitch, Vy.

Comment: @Jamiec Captains briefing

Answer (score 2):

I have never used any checklist or Mnemonic for this, but I do use it as a sneaky way to make myself look professional to my passengers while *really* using it to remind myself what the hell I'm actually meant to be doing.

Typically it will contain the following

- What will happen in the next 5 minutes ("We'll line up on the runway when told to.... we will begin rolling..... we will lift off at about [speed]")
- What will happen immediately after take off ("We will climb until X, at which point I will turn [left|right] and head towards Y")
- What the intention of the flight is ("We will continue via X & Y to Z")
- Any quick emergency procedures which might be necessary (Much like your instructor demonstrated, along with briefly what the passenger should do in case of this emergency.)

I do this at the hold when with an instructor, or experienced pilot in the other seat. If its an inexperienced or nervous flyer I take longer about it, usually sitting in the aircraft prior to startup.